# Преобразовать угол поворота в соотношение x и y

Tags: javascript, тригонометрия

Я не могу понять как мне преобразовать угол в соотношение x и y
(Я имею в виду в два числа модули которых в сумме дают 1)

Например:

- 90 = 1 и 0
- -90 = -1 и 0
- 0 = 0 и 1
- 180 = 0 и -1
- 45 = 0.5 и 0.5

Можете сделать пример двух таких функций для x и y пожалуйста

Comment: Поясните, почему 90 = 1,0, а 45 = 0,5,0,5?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @SwaD Представьте что у вас есть возможность "идти (1) шаг в направлении (90)" и возможность "изменить свой x на (1) и y на (0)". Это будет одно и тоже. Суть в том что первой возможности у меня нет, и я хочу реализовать её как "изменить x на ("x от угла (90)") и y на ("y от угла (90)")"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Описание

По описанию вопроса становиться понятно, что вы хотите получить соотношение на которое разделяет линия прямой угол. Легче всего это делать с помощью тригонометрии:

[image]

То есть нам дают `a`. Мы считаем `cos(a)` и `sin(a)`, потом считаем их сумму и вычисляем какая из них какую часть занимает.

#### Решение

```js
const alpha = window.prompt(`Enter the angle`);
function degToRad(angle) {
  return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
}
const x = Math.sin(degToRad(alpha));
const y = Math.cos(degToRad(alpha));
const sum = Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y);
const xCoefficent = x / sum;
const yCoefficent = y / sum;
console.log(`X: ${xCoefficent.toFixed(4)}, Y: ${yCoefficent.toFixed(4)}`);
```

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что нужно!